# Function returns wrong value and one of the characters is unexpected

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote two basic functions in order to convert Celsius into Fahrenheit and vice-versa.
 My problem is that the first conversion is wrong and I don't know why it returned the wrong value. And I also don't know why there is a "Â" after the numbers.

The functions are the following:

```
function celsiusToFahrenheit (celsius) {
let fahrenheit = celsius * (9/5) + 32;
document.getElementById('fahrenheit').innerHTML = celsius + "ºC is " +         celsius + "ºF";
}
function fahrenheitToCelsius (fahrenheit) {
let celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) / (9/5);
document.getElementById('celsius').innerHTML = fahrenheit + "ºF is " +      celsius + "ºC";
}
celsiusToFahrenheit(25);
fahrenheitToCelsius(120);
```

But when I see it on my browser what I get is:

```
25ÂºC is 25ÂºF

120ÂºF is 48.888888888888886ÂºC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the first conversion is wrong

Change the second `celsius` to `fahrenheit` here:

```
document.getElementById('fahrenheit').innerHTML = celsius + "ºC is " + celsius + "ºF";
```

> I also don't know why there is a "Â" after the numbers.

You can overcome the character encoding issue by using the HTML entity for degrees (`&deg;`):

```
document.getElementById('celsius').innerHTML = fahrenheit + "&deg;F is " + celsius + "&deg;C";
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius) {
  let fahrenheit = celsius * (9 / 5) + 32;
  document.getElementById('fahrenheit').innerHTML = celsius + "&deg;C is " + fahrenheit + "&deg;F";
}

function fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit) {
  let celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) / (9 / 5);
  document.getElementById('celsius').innerHTML = fahrenheit + "&deg;F is " + celsius + "&deg;C";
}
celsiusToFahrenheit(25);
fahrenheitToCelsius(120);
```

```html
<div id="fahrenheit"></div>
<div id="celsius"></div>
```